# decimal.ToString("C") produces ¤ currency symbol on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project where I am rendering some currency numbers through a Razor HTML page.

**View Model**

```
class MyModel
{
    public decimal Money { get; set; } = 1.23
}
```

**Razor Page**

```
@model MyModel
<p>@Model.Money.ToString("C")</p>
```

This project is deployed to Azure App Service.

On a Windows App Service plan (and my local Windows 10 machine), this produces "$1.23" as expected. However, if I deploy the same project to a Linux App Service Plan it renders "¤1.23".

According to Google:

> The currency sign (¤) is a character used to denote an unspecified currency.

Any idea what there is a difference between the two OS here? Do I need to explicitly set the culture or something on Linux?

Comment: It's using the invariant culture by default

Comment: Does this help?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is caused by that the linux did not configure locale.

You could set the thread culture in your program like below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: I signed in to make this comment after years of lurking and not finding a direct answer for years - this is dead on. Windows host? I didn't have a problem, but on linux? Just the ¤ and encoding I'd never seen. But drop the CultureInfo line Edward mentioned in your Program.cs (mine's "classless", still works) and the ¤ goes to a $. This works, unceremoniously in .net 6/7. Literally copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

What Culture is your code running? I guess that azure don't know the current culture and is showing you a generic money currency symbol.

I recommand that you use this function, where provider is your CultureInfo object.

```
public string ToString (string format, IFormatProvider provider);
```

Comment: No culture has been set as far as I know. I have never set a culture for the application before since this has not been an issue on Windows. I guess culture is explicitly required on these Linux machines?

Comment: It still a good practices to set the Culture on every type conversion and ToString function call. You might run your program with the default culture use a dot "." for decimal separator, but a customer will have a culture that the separator is comma ",".

Comment: @Bestter Without passing in a culture, it defaults to the current thread's culture, which it gets from  `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`.  It's unnecessary to pass a culture into every `ToString` invocation.

Comment: @Amy: You're right in a certain way, but it's always depend of your context. You might let your customer customize is language then you will need to pass the culture to every ToString and Parse function. Or you can control the current thread culture, like you said.